# the usage of "will" and "be going to"

Tags: expressions, future

Which expression is preferencial?
It is going to be the year of horse next year.
It will be the year of horse next year.

Comment: Both are correct. Both can refer to the future. They're used for different situations.

Comment: @JohnLawler could you specify the different situations by sentences?

Comment: No. Mostly it's a matter of timing -- _I'm gonna go_ is one stress group, and so is _I'll go_, so you have your choice, and sometimes you want to have a lot of little syllables, but sometimes you want the edges to stand out alone. It depends on how fast you're talking and what attitude you're putting on your sentences with intonation and rhythm.